# Джанго. На сервере статические файлы не обновляются

Tags: python, django

Проблема такова: залил когда-то на сервер статик файлы, не менял их много времени, уже забыл что да как там, понадобилось поменять. Поменял - ничего, сервер их не поменял, при том что я чистил кэш. Посоветовали в интернете collectstatic, но он не работает, ибо выдает ошибку, что отсутствует django, хотя он есть. Главный вопрос: как обновить static файлы?

Comment: А как Вы их раздаёте? Общее решение — `python manage.py collectstatic`. Если ругается, что нет `django`, проверьте окружение в котором работаете. Может, забыли активировать `venv`?

Comment: Это зависит от того, как на вашем сервере static файлы вообще устроены и работают. Без знания этого ответить на вопрос не получится, и Django тут в общем-то ни при чём

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты скорее всего не вошел в виртуальное окружение. Сначала активируй его, а потом выполняй `collectstatic`. И что у тебя за сервер?

Comment: Да, я во первых не вошел в виртуальное окружение, во вторых статик файлы лежали не там где я думал, я пути не правильно прописал.

Comment: Ну вот. Теперь работает?